# vb.net downloading file using WebClient always corrupted file

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to download a ZIP file from Dropbox but every time I try it stops and only downloads ~100 kb of the file. It seems to corrupt any file I download from it, but however if I try to download using a normal browser it works.

```
Dim remoteUri As String = "https://www.dropbox.com/-/-------/test.zip?dl=0"
Dim fileName As String = "test.zip"
Dim myStringWebResource As String = Nothing
Dim myWebClient As New WebClient()
myStringWebResource = remoteUri + fileName
myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource, fileName)
```

Comment: Did you try asking Dropbox?

Comment: then im downloading it from normal browser it works.

Comment: Did you try downloading from *another browser* (one that you are not signed into Dropbox on).?

Comment: Yes. I tried and it works

Comment: I have a hard time understanding `myStringWebResource = remoteUri + fileName`. That would be `...dl=0test.zip` which is wrong as url.

Comment: Did you try `Dim remoteUri As String = "https://www.dropbox.com/-/-------/test.zip?dl=0"` without the GET request (take off the `?dl=0`)?

Comment: yes i had tryed but it didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your remoteUri is wrong. You're adding the filename twice. That gives you a bad url.

```
Dim remoteUri As String = "https://www.dropbox.com/-/-------/{0}?dl=1"
Dim fileName As String = "test.zip"
Dim myStringWebResource As String = Nothing
Dim myWebClient As New WebClient()
myStringWebResource = String.Format(remoteUri, fileName)
myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource, fileName)
```

Try adding dl=1 to force download.

Comment: i checked your solution. i have same issues. it stops and only downloads ~100 kb